# Find all numbers within square brackets using REGEX

Tags: php, regex

I searched some posts but can't find the right solution for my problem.

I want all numbers that are within `[]`.

I tested the following regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com):

```
\\[.\*([0-9]++).*\\] .....    /gU <- Flags
```

Test string:

```
Test bla bla [us_image_slider ids="6207,6204,6203,6199,6484,6470" nav="thumbs" img_size="us_img_size_2"] some numbers 232323 [img="344"] and [daas 23344 2333]2323 ( hello 233 )
```

---

My Regex finds only the first number and not the others within the square brackets :(

Result has to be :
match0 = 6207
match1 = 6204
...

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Could you please format your question so it's more readable?

Comment: It doesn't match other digits since you are matching everything `.*` after first match. You are after something like a positive lookahead [**`\d+(?=[^][]*\])`**](https://regex101.com/r/9LVhB9/1/)

Comment: Example above you have open bracket what it is happening if you have [ bla bla 123,456, bla [abg,789] bla it should return 
123,456, 789 or just 789 ?

Comment: problem solved thank you very much, i just miss typed your regex ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't match other digits since you are matching everything `.*` after first match.

You are looking for something like a positive lookahead:

```
\d+(?=[^][]*\])
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/9LVhB9/1/)